# GWT : How to apply a "scroll !important" on RichTextArea

Tags: gwt, richtextarea

In GWT 2.7, I want my scroll bar is visible all the time on my RichTextArea, even when empty.

Usually, on my FlowPanel I can simply apply a

```
    overflow: scroll !important;
```

But on a RichTextArea, it does not work.

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this :

```
RichTextArea rtArea = new RichTextArea();                 
rtArea.getElement().getStyle().setOverflow(Overflow.SCROLL);
```

You can also set height and width as per your choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
unfortunately this does not work , I had already tried...
For example, 
this does not work : 
`rtArea.getElement().getStyle().setOverflow(Overflow.SCROLL);`
but this, it's ok :    
`rtArea.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("red");`

I don't know why ...

Comment: Actually GWT render RichTextArea as iframe. And scroll is only visible when entered text is exceed width of text area.